# The Philosphers stone in Flash TV series

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

I just finished *The Flash* Season 3 and certain things are unclear to me. As far as the TV show goes, I understood that Tracy Bran's Speed force Bazooka didn't work with Savitar because Savitar had the philosophers stone in hand.

Please forgive my ignorance of the fact that I have never read any Flash comics till now. I only watched the show.

So my question is:

**What exactly is the connection of the philosophers stone with the Speed Force?**

Comment: http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Philosopher%27s_Stone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the DC Universe, **The Philosopher's Stone** is the name given to several powerful magical items which possess magical or alchemical properties to manipulate the material and/or events of the world.

With respect to this instance, The Philosopher's Stone is an item that was forged from the speed force, and thus, cit has some kind of affinity to the speed force.

Quoting **[this article](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Philosopher%27s_Stone)**:

> The Philosopher's Stone is made of calcified Speed Force energy, and
>   is the first ever artifact responsible for the creation of meta-humans
>   in ancient times. It can also shoot powerful blasts of energy, fast
>   enough to hinder a speedster because of it being pure speed force.
>   Alchemy used it to return powers people once had in Flashpoint
>   timeline as servants of Savitar.